# how to hide a block from search page in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I need to hide a block from the search results page.In the block's `Visibility settings`, I selected `All pages except those listed` and typed search in the box.But the url of the search page is `example.com/search/node/searchword`. So the block is still visible in the search results page. How can I hide the block ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need a wildcard.

```
search* or search/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write `search/*` after selecting `All pages except those listed`

Thats all...